# Delete from table where id in (*php variable*) returns error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I working in a php application where I must delete the selected items from a list where each item haves their own ID from mysql database, everything goes ok until execute the query in php.

This is the error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

this is the String that I execute in the query:

```
$queryDE =  "delete from md5_agenda
             where id_empresa = $empi
             and id_unidade = $unii
             and id_usuario = $usrr
             and id_item_agenda in ($deletar);"
```

The variable `$deletar` receives their value from post method and their value is like: `35,36,47,...` and can be one ore many different values

But my problem is if I change `$deletar` for the exactly values everything goes fine, but if I use the php variable with THE EXACTLY SAME VALUE it doesn't work and returns the previous error message, I have no more ideas about what to do... I wanna keep in this way where I can choose all IDs that I want delete, without repeat the query.

Thanks.

edit:
[image: the echo returns the $queryDE and the mysql_error()]

Comment: PHP and SQL are different languages that run on different environments. What counts is the *generated* SQL that reaches MySQL.

Comment: `echo $queryDE` please

Comment: It's got to be `id_item_agenda IN (35,36,47)` or `id_item_agenda IN ('35','36','47')` (not recommended), but not `id_item_agenda IN ('35,36,47')`.

Comment: To echo what @hank is saying, you need to output the query as it is being fed into MySQL. You said the values are coming from POST. if you're not sanitizing them before putting them into your query, it could easily create problems like this.

Comment: The echo returns "delete from md5_agenda where id_empresa = 1 and id_unidade = 1 and id_usuario = 1 and id_item_agenda in (491,490,489,488,487);"

Comment: There's no syntax error in this sql statement.

Comment: The query does look correct. Are you sure this is the query causing the error?

Comment: I'm sure! if a replace the variable with the EXACTLY string everything goes right, but if I use the php variable don't...

Comment: I edit with the screen error

Comment: What does `echo $queryDE` show if you execute `header('Content-Type:text/plain; charset=UTF-8')` first?

Comment: I bet it's the output of the list. Trailing comma or something like this. @acca90 please add debug code and paste it

Comment: It is already in UTF-8 charset

Comment: @acca90 But is it `text/plain`? Judging how it is all in single line, you are seeing it as html and as such you may not see some text.

Comment: Cthulhu, thanks! I found an unknown character in first position of the variable

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($deletar as $val)
{
             $queryDE =  "delete from md5_agenda
             where id_empresa = $empi
             and id_unidade = $unii
             and id_usuario = $usrr
             and id_item_agenda = $val;"
}

your code is not working because $deleter is return multiple value.
check code it's working.
```

Comment: Certainly not the best approach, easier to implode array first and then run a single query (with `in`).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a safe parametrized query?

```
$db =new PDO('... your connection string ... ');
$stmt = $db->prepare("delete from md5_agenda
         where id_empresa = :empi
         and id_unidade = :unii
         and id_usuario = :usrr
         and id_item_agenda in (:deletar);");
$stmt->execute(array(
                ':empi' => $empi,
                ':unii' => $unii,
                ':usrr' => $usrr,
                ':deletar' => $deletar
              )
);
```

Comment: no that wouldn't do for the IN operator, see my comment to the OP.

Comment: You have to add a separate placeholder for every item in a list, it is easier to do that with positional placeholders

Comment: Seriously, why wouldn't you test it first?